Extension cord into outlet on ceiling?
I need to provide power to groups of tables, and it is impractical/dangerous to run cords from the walls to the tables, especially with children running around and potentially stumbling over cords, even if those run through cable ramps.
The idea was to put outlets on the ceiling, facing down, and plugging in extension cords with a few outlets, that will then lie on the tables.
Is this a good idea? Is it according to code? Should we use twist-lock plugs or better not? Or chinese finger cable supports, and regular plugs?
I'm in Virginia, USA.

Extension cords are for temporary use only.  This sounds more like a commercial or business place which has special rules above what is allowed in a home.  I would check with your local building department for what you can do.

What are the power requirements at the tables?

Outlets on tables where water/drinks can be spilt on them isn't a good  idea.

I’m voting to close this question because  it doesn't appear to be about home improvement.

It doesn't strike me as a good idea for the purpose it's suggested, but there are ceiling light fixtures with outlets, typically used in basements and similar spaces, and it's not uncommon to use those for temporary purposes like powering a tool, an additional light, or a basement work table.

@Crip59 if the tables are not fixed in place it's temporary

Yes, it is temporary, for maybe 2 h at a time for a given event, then the extension cords would be removed.

There are basically two options:
Floor
If you (a) have the ability to install things in the floor and (b) have access below the floor to run cables/conduit, then you can install floor receptacles, such as this Leviton from Home Depot:

Ceiling
Ceiling receptacles should only be used for things that (a) are mounted near the ceiling and (b) can't be hardwired. A typical good use of a ceiling receptacle is for a projector. You should not use extension cords from ceiling receptacles because the extension cord will get pulled on and eventually either fall out (not good!) or get loose and have a poor connection which can be a real fire hazard.
The solution is a pendant, which is basically a receptacle (or more typically several receptacles) on a hanging heavy duty cord. Often they are retractable which makes them useful for situations where room usage changes a lot. The catch is that while installation is often easier than for a floor receptacle (because ceilings can either have surface mount conduit or have space and access above for running cables, unlike floors which are often much harder to work with (except during the initial building process), particularly on the ground floor if there is no basement or crawl space, a UL/ETL/etc. listed properly designed pendant receptacle is not an inexpensive item. Basically these are commonly used in factories and warehouses and large retail stores, etc. and so they are not commonly available for consumer installation, unlike floor receptacles which are available at Home Depot and similar stores at a reasonable price.

Yeah, I've seen pendant, but those, or cord reels, have the problem of being in the way of tall-ish people when the cords are not needed, since the ceiling height is only ~7 ft.
